# How do I fetch a list of >130 entities by ID from Dynamics 365?

Tags: soap, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-webapi

I have a list of entity IDs that I need to fetch from Dynamics into my application. Using the WebAPI the query must be URL encoded and passed as a GET request which limits the number of entities to about 130 (more than that hits the URL length limit)

Previously we could use the SOAP endpoint to make a single POST request but this is on the deprecation path.

So what is the recommended way to make such a query now?

Some options:

- Manually paginate and run through the WebAPI making parallel requests. This is less than ideal, especially when making abstractions around Dynamics since requests may fail.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @Guido Preite I was able to use a WebAPI [batch request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/execute-batch-operations-using-web-api). Basically you issue the GET request with the 130+ entities but encode it in the batch request body to work around the character limit. I'll post the request below for Postman ...

Post to `{{myDynamicsURL}}/api/data/v9.0/$batch`

Headers

```
Authorization:Bearer {{token}}
Content-Type:multipart/mixed;boundary=batch_AAA123 
Accept:application/json
Cache-Control:no-cache
OData-MaxVersion:4.0
OData-Version:4.0
Prefer:odata.maxpagesize=500, odata.include-annotations="*", return=representation
```

Body

```
--batch_AAA123
Content-Type: application/http  
Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary

GET {{myDynamicsURL}}/connections?$filter=(connectionid eq 9b704176-2f60-e911-a830-000d3a385a17 or connectionid eq 1ccc526c-2e6c-e911-a831-000d3a385a17 ... <REST OF QUERIES HERE>) HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json

--batch_AAA123--
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can query using a FetchXML passed inside a POST request

https://dreamingincrm.com/2017/01/15/executing-large-fetchxml-with-webapi/

Comment: Amazing so I can just use a WebAPI [batch request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/execute-batch-operations-using-web-api). I tried out my query and it works. I'll post here.